# Unable to read HDF5 file in R which was written using Python

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, hdf5

I wrote a `Pandas` dataframe on disk using `to_hdf()` function of a dataframe (Pandas / Python 2.7).

I want to read this dataframe in R-environment. I am using the `rhdf5` package in R to read the file.

Python code to dump the dataframe

```
data.to_hdf('myDataFrame.h5', 'table', append=True) #data is a pandas dataframe
```

R code to read it

```
library(rhdf5)
data <- h5read("myDataFrame.h5", "table")
```

How can this be achieved? Is there a better way to exchange dataframes between the 2 languages? I don't want to involve `.csv` as it will lose all meta information and will be slower to parse every time I read.

I don't have error messages, only a couple of warnings. But the `data` I read is nowhere similar to what I want and I am unable to find what I stored. This is what it looks like when I try to explore the read object. Whereas the dataframe I stored has shape (1,400,000 x 267).

```
List of 2
 $ _i_table:List of 1
  ..$ index:List of 10
  .. ..$ abounds  : int [1:680(1d)] 0 2048 4096 6144 8192 10240 12288 14336 16384 18432 ...
  .. ..$ bounds   : int [1:135, 1:5] 2048 4096 6144 8192 10240 12288 14336 16384 18432 20480 ...
  .. ..$ indices  : int [1:278528, 1:5] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..$ indicesLR: int [1:278528(1d)] 2165 2165 2165 2165 2165 2165 2165 2165 2165 2165 ...
  .. ..$ mbounds  : int [1:680(1d)] 1024 3072 5120 7168 9216 11264 13312 15360 17408 19456 ...
  .. ..$ mranges  : int [1:5(1d)] 140288 418816 697344 975872 1254400
  .. ..$ ranges   : int [1:2, 1:5] 0 278527 278528 557055 557056 835583 835584 1114111 1114112 1392639
  .. ..$ sorted   : int [1:278528, 1:5] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  .. ..$ sortedLR : int [1:278665(1d)] 1392640 1392641 1392642 1392643 1392644 1392645 1392646 1392647 1392648 1392649 ...
  .. ..$ zbounds  : int [1:680(1d)] 2047 4095 6143 8191 10239 12287 14335 16383 18431 20479 ...
 $ table   :'data.frame':   1400000 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ index         : int [1:1400000(1d)] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  ..$ values_block_0: num [1:1400000(1d)] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ values_block_1: num [1:1400000(1d)] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ values_block_2: num [1:1400000(1d)] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ values_block_3: num [1:1400000(1d)] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ values_block_4: num [1:1400000(1d)] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Comment: you could try [feather](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/03/29/feather/)

Comment: what is your error message? and what is your pytables version (in Python) and HDF5 version in R?

Comment: I initially tried to do that. But the server I am working on doesn't have a C++ compiler and I don't have permissions to install and I couldn't find a `wheel` file for `feather-format`.

Comment: @Shivendra, can you install Anaconda for a __local__ user?

Comment: It is installed system wide and I have tried `conda install feather-format -c conda-forge`. It also fails saying `UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - feather-format
  - python 2.7*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
`